# Calculate average temperature in CSV

Tags: python

Below is my data set.

I want to calculate the average temperature of each station. It is more desired if I can remove zero (noise) data.

How can I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKfIK.png)

I have no idea on how to start with.

Comment: where is the dataset..!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry that i miss the data as i am first time using this platform. just post it as image! thanks for sharing!

Comment: Start learning Python, or just use [Miller tool](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/10min/) to get the job done

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [standard csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to iterate over rows, collect all temperatures to the list `t` and do something like `sum(t) / len(t)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the data into a `pandas.DataFrame` and use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` method:

```py
import pandas as pd

file = #your csv file
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df = df.drop(df[df['temp'] == 0].index)

print(df.groupby('ID')[['temp']].mean())
```

Gives:

```py
    temp
ID      
1   20.5
2   32.1
3   14.4
```

Note: the file I used looks like...

```
ID,stuff,temp
1,3,20
1,6,20.1
1,7,21.4
2,1,30.2
2,3,0
2,2,34
3,7,0
3,6,0
3,2,14.4
```

If wanting to turn that data into a column, you create a dictionary and use it to 'replace' (but not really) a new column in the DataFrame:

```py
mean = df.groupby('ID')[['temp']].mean() # Store this into a variable

groups = {}

for i in mean.itertuples(): # Iterate over the values
    groups[i[0]] = i[1]
    
df['avg_temp'] = df['ID'].replace(groups) # Create a new column

print(df)
```

Gives:

```py
   ID  stuff  temp  avg_temp
0   1      3  20.0      20.5
1   1      6  20.1      20.5
2   1      7  21.4      20.5
3   2      1  30.2      32.1
5   2      2  34.0      32.1
8   3      2  14.4      14.4
```

Comment: if i want to assign the average temperature into the df as a new column, how can i make it?

Comment: @JasmineLee answered your question